# What is the best implementation of custom extension point

Tags: java, validation, oop, design-patterns

I need to make an extension point for custom validation rules in java. Can you help me to find the best way to do it?

My code looks like this

```
...
public myClass() {
...
//some business logic
customValidator.validate(event); //custom validator
...
}
```

I know that it is suitable to use base `Validator` interface and implement it with custom validators.

```
   interface Validator {
   public static Boolean validate();
   }
   public class TrueValidator implements Validator {
   public static Boolean validate() { return true;}
   }

   public class TrueValidator implements Validator {
   public static Boolean validate() { return false;}
   }
```

I want to know what is the best pattern of calling validation depending on some `String` variable. Is it okay just to get class with Reflection API? I will get my `String` from database, create `Class` and create instance of it.

The other solution I know is to make `Validator` factory and get `Validator` by `String` variable, but I think that it is too excessive.

Can you recommend me somethink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to instantiate a validator based on a string? There are multiple possible implementations and I can't tell which one is best, but the implementation you choose should be abstracted away in a factory. You do not want your code littered with logic to find and instantiate those validators from strings.

E.g.

```
public interface Validator {
    public boolean validate(ThingToValidate thingToValidate);
}

public final class TrueValidator implements Validator {
    //Note that the method is not static
    public boolean validate(ThingToValidate thingToValidate) {
        return true;
    }
}

public interface ValidatorFactory {
    public Validator createFromType(String type);
}

//Concrete validation factory using reflection
public final class ReflectiveValidatorFactory implements ValidatorFactory {
    public Validator createFromType(String type) {
        /*Use reflection to resolve the class based on the interface
        and naming conventions and/or annotations. 
        You may also cache the validator to avoid re-resolving it.*/
    }
}

//Concrete validation factory where validator types are hard-coded.
public final class HardcodedValidatorFactory implements ValidatorFactory {
    public Validator createFromType(String type) {
        switch (type) {
            case 'True': return new TrueValidator();
            //...
        }
    }
}

//Example of a client class that would use the ValidatorFactory
public final class ValidationService {
    private final ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;

    public ValidationService(ValidatorFactory validatorFactory) {
        this.validatorFactory = validatorFactory;
    }

    public boolean validate(String validatorType, ThingToValidate thingToValidate) {
        Validator validator = validatorFactory.createFromType(validatorType);

        return validator.validate(thingToValidate);
    }
}
```

Please note that your `Valiator.validate` method shouldn't be static! I understand that since validators are stateless you may want to re-use the same instance hence the idea to make the `validate` method static, but doing so will make your design much less flexible and testable.

If you wish to ensure that the same validator instance is re-used, then you can make sure that only one concrete `ValidatorFactory` is instantiated in your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) and that this factory caches the validators.